# Python XML Serialisation using attributes

Tags: python, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I am trying to serialise (several) complicated datastructures from python into a very explicit XML string.

In C#, this is as easy as creating the data structure, marking fields with some attributes such as [XmlElement] or [XmlAttribute], and essentially calling "serialise".

However, I cant find similar functionality in python. I can see loads of examples of manually parsing the structure, but this is not really suitable for my needs.

Is there anyway of simulating this C# functionality;

```
public enum eType {

    [XmlEnum("multi")]
    Multiple,

    [XmlEnum("mutex1")]
    Single,

    [XmlEnum("product")]
    Product,

    [XmlEnum("alias")]
    Alias
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("root")]
public class RootClass{

    public RootClass() {
        Metadata = new Metadata ();
        FeatureDictionary = new FeatureDictionary ();
    }

    [XmlElement("metadata")]
    public Metadata Metadata { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("feature-dictionary")]
    public FeatureDictionary FeatureDictionary { get; set; }

}

[Serializable]
public class Metadata {

    public Metadata() {
        Meta = new List<Meta> ();
    }

    [XmlAttribute("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("url")]
    public string URL { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("view")]
    public string View { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("meta")]
    public List<Meta> Meta { get; set; }

}
```

In python?

Please bear in mind that the snippet above is around 1/20th of the code defining the XML in C#.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the C# syntax, so I can't give specifics, but wrapping your python objects with custom built decorators should do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One reasonable approach to this is to use [python descriptors](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/gist.github.com/ChrisBeaumont/5758381/raw/descriptor_writeup.ipynb) to create properties on the object which know how to serialize and deserialize themselves.  Descriptors are the mechanism python uses to create the @property decorators: the contain getter and setter methods and can have local state so they make a good staging ground in between your data and your xml.  Coupled with a class or  decorator that automates the process of bulk serializing/deserializing the descriptors attached to an object, you have the guts of the C# XML serialization system.

Generically, you'd want code to look like this (using the infamous XML ISBN example:

```
 @xmlobject("Book")  
 class Book( object  ):

    author = XElement( 'AuthorsText' )
    title = XElement( 'Title' )
    bookId = XAttrib( 'book_id' )
    isbn = IntAttrib( 'isbn' )
    publisher = XInstance( 'PublisherText', Publisher )
```

The assigment syntax here is creating class-level descriptors for what will be all the fields in the instance ( author, title, etc).  Each descriptor looks like a regular field to other python code, so you can do things like:

```
book.author = 'Joyce, James'
```

and so on.  Internally each descriptor stores and xml node or attribute, and when called on to serialize it will return the appropriate XML:

```
from xml.etree.cElementTree import ElementTree, Element

class XElement( object ):
    '''
    Simple XML serializable field
    '''

    def __init__( self, path):           
        self.path = path
        self._xml = Element(path) # using an ElementTree or lxml element as internal storage

    def get_xml( self, inst ):
        return inst._xml

    def _get_element( self ):
        return self.path

    def _get_attribute( self ):
        return None

    # the getter and setter push values into the underlying xml and return them from there
    def __get__( self, instance, owner=None ):
         myxml = self.get_xml( instance )
         underlying = myxml.find( self.path )
         return underlying.text 

    def __set__( self, instance, value, owner=None ):
        myxml= self._get_xml( instance )
        underlying = myxml.find( self.path )
        underlying.text = value
```

The corresponding XAttrib class does the same thing, except in an attribute instead of a an element.

```
class XAttrib( XElement):
    '''
     Wraps a property in an attribute on the containing xml tag specified by 'path'
    '''

    def __get__( self, instance, owner=None ):
        return self._get_xml( instance ).attrib[self.path]  
        # again, using ElementTree under the hood

    def __set__( self, instance, value, owner=None ):
        myxml = self._get_xml( instance )
        has_element = myxml.get( self.path, 'NOT_FOUND' )
        if has_element == 'NOT_FOUND':
           raise Exception, "instance has no element path"
        myxml.set( self.path, value )

    def _get_element( self ):
        return None  #so outside code knows we are an attrib

    def _get_attribute( self ):
        return self.path
```

To tie it all together, the owning class needs to set up the descriptors at initialization time so each instance-level descriptor is pointed at an XML node in the owning instance's own XML element.  That way the changes to instance props are automatically reflected in the owner's XML.

```
        def create_defaults( target_cls):
             # where target class is the serializable class, eg 'Book'
             # here _et_xml() would return the class level Element, just
             # as in the XElement and XAttribute.  Good use for a decorator!

             myxml = target_cls.get_xml()

             default_attribs = [item for item in target_cls.__class__.__dict__.values() 
                                 if issubclass( item.__class__, XElement) ]
             #default attribs will be all the descriptors in the target class

             for item in default_attribs:
                element_name = item._get_element()
                #update the xml for the owning class with 
                # all the XElements
                if element_name:
                    new_element = Element( element_name )
                    new_element.text = str( item.DEFAULT_VAL )
                    myxml.append( new_element )

                # then update the owning XML with the attributes 
             for item in default_attribs:
                 attribpath = item._get_attribute()
                 if attrib:
                     myxml.set( attribpath, str( item.DEFAULT_VAL ) )
```

Apologies if this code doesn't run off the bat - I stripped it down from a working example but i may have introduced bugs while trying to make it readable and removing details specific to my application.